# How to set button object to an image

Tags: android

I need to customize the look and feel of my android application. I need a PNG file I created to show in place of the button view's default appearance. How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
you can set the backgroung of Button as follows.



 <Button android:id="@+id/button01" 
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                         android:background="@drawable/savebuttonselect" 
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
```

and here savebuttonselect is a xml file used to change the button image on state change

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/save_btn_roll" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/save_btn_roll" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/save_btn" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a little code snippet I'm using when I need a custom button:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/button_active" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/button_enabled" />

<item android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/button_enabled" />
<item android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/button_enabled"/>
```

It helps you defined your drawables for every button state and changes them automatically. Just create an XML file with this code inside and put it as a background drawable of your button. Hope this helps.